# Changeable variable of all rows in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a variable that uses a value in one column in a table, do a function with that # and move to the next row in that column to do the same function again.

I have tried couple methods and have problems finishing it, not sure if I'm on the right path.

from this table:

```
INSERT #DirectoryTree (subdirectory,depth,isfile)
EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree 'D:\Documents and Settings\arabrya\Desktop\Project\mdb files',1,1;


SELECT * FROM #DirectoryTree
ORDER BY id;
GO
```

where the output is:

```
id      subdirectory
1   4483167B.mdb
2   4536807.mdb
3   4536897A.mdb
4   4536897B.mdb
5   4546780.mdb
6   4619524.mdb
7   4662828.mdb
8   4700416.mdb
9   4706729.mdb
10  4789161.mdb
11  4789161A.mdb
12  4808925.mdb
13  4882574A.mdb
14  4910394A.mdb
15  4986274.mdb
16  976767.mdb
17  976767A.mdb
18  976767B.mdb
```

to do this:

```
INSERT INTO [test5].[dbo].[tblJob]
SELECT *  FROM OPENDATASOURCE(
'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Data Source="\\bhr05\mdb\' + @varName + '.mdb"'
```

where @varName is the variable from the column 'subdirectory' in '#DirectoryTree' table. Is this possible? How if yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to declare a cursor to loop over the table:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(20) -- database name 

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT subdirectory 
FROM #DirectoryTree 

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @subdirectory    

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO [test5].[dbo].[tblJob]
    SELECT *  FROM OPENDATASOURCE(
    'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
    'Data Source="\\bhr05\mdb\' + @subdirectory + '.mdb"' 

END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```